# Stop thread safely

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

i write multi thread program.

I want to ask what is difference between `TerminateThread` and `ExitThread`?

This is my code snippet when `WM_DESTROY` received :

```
void CleanAll()
{
    DWORD dwExit[MAX_THREAD];
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    {
        GetExitCodeThread(hThread[i], &dwExit[i]);
        // I used ExitThread(dwExit[i]); previously
        TerminateThread(hThread[i], dwExit[i]);
        CloseHandle(hThread[i]);
    }
}
```

I used `ExitThread()` previously, but my program stikk in Task Manager, so I change it to `TerminateThread()` and my program  is gone from Task Manager.

Any advance explanation is very appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

TerminateThread forces **another thread** to exit.  You should avoid calling it at all costs as it will stop a thread dead in it's tracks without any chance to cleanup.  This includes any CRT memory allocated.

ExitThread is for the **currently running thread** to stop itself nice and cleanly.  When you called it above, you likely forced the main (UI) thread to exit and likely left the running threads still lingering around. Hence, your program was still running as evidenced in Task Manager.  GetExitCodeThread was also likely failing since the threads had not actually exited.

But the right way to stop a thread is to cleanly signal by any clean means necessary that it should exit.  **Then allow the threads to exit on their own** before allowing the main thread to exit. In the following example, I used a global flag to indicate to threads that they should exit.  But that assumes your threads will always have a chance to poll for the global bool state.  Another cleaner approach is to have each thread call WaitForSingleObject on an event handle.  When the event handle is signalled, the thread checks the global variable and exits if needed.

```
bool global_Need_ToExit;  // use a bool or replace with an event handle the thread shoudl wait on

void CleanAll()
{
    //signal all threads to exit
    global_Need_ToExit = true;

    DWORD dwExit[MAX_THREAD];
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    {
        // actually wait for the thread to exit
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread[i], WAIT_INFINITE);

        // get the thread's exit code (I'm not sure why you need it)
        GetExitCodeThread(hThread[i], &dwExit[i]);

        // cleanup the thread
        CloseHandle(hThread[i]);
        hThread[i] = NULL;
    }
}

DWORD __stdcall YourThreadFunction(void* pData)
{

    while (global_Need_To_Exit == false)
    {
        // do more work
    }

    return 0; // same as ExitThread(0);
}
```

Comment: With this purpose, one should not use a non-atomic type without declaring it as `volatile`. Compilers generally optimise loops, therefore other threads may not see an updated value. By declaring a variable `volatile` you tell the compiler that it should re-read its value from its storage location every time, rather than assume its previously read value from a processor register or cache. Other than that, great answer! +1

Comment: @Selbie: Thanks Selbie, your advise works for me like a charm

Comment: @jweyrich - Agreed in principal. Assuming he makes at least one non-inline function call between polling that variable he should be ok, because the compiler can't assume the variable won't change between function calls. He technically needs a "conditonal variable" for improved safety across multicore/multiproc architectures, which is easily implemented by using InterlockedExchange* funcs or any lock function on that variable.

Comment: For the cancallation token, rather than using `volatile` which has different meanings in different compilers, I'd use `std::atomic<bool>`. I see no need for a condition variable.

Comment: The problem is that doing this instead of a semaphore means your program will only exit after all sleep() calls have completed - you can't use a timed wait to exit early if the program is shut down. Which means you can't ever just wait on a queue, you have to busy wait with a short timeout so you can check the global variable. So the answer is a good start, but shouldn't be extended beyond very simple cases.

Comment: I have a question about 'When the event handle is signalled, the thread checks the global variable and exits if needed.', here how the worker thread will get chance to check the global variable if it is stuck in some infinite loop or doing some task which takes a long time?

Comment: @AnuragDaware - how one thread signals to another that it "needs to exit" is a design issue that the developer has to make. In my simple example, that wouldn't work if the thread is "stuck" doing a long blocking operation. On Windows, Most blocking calls are usually based on I/O or COM - both of which have a scenario for operating asynchronously. Integrating that into a polling model for the exit condition would need to be done.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, but the top voted answer says to use ExitThread because it will "stop itself nice and cleanly".
This is simply not true. The documentation states:
***ExitThread is the preferred method of exiting a thread in C code. However, in C++ code, the thread is exited before any destructors can be called or any other automatic cleanup can be performed. Therefore, in C++ code, you should return from your thread function.***
I learned this the hard way by following advice from a forum to use ExitThread and then spending hours wondering where the heck all my memory leaks were coming from. Yeah, that's for C++, but that's what this question is regarding. And actually, even for C there is a caveat ***"A thread in an executable that is linked to the static C run-time library (CRT) should use _beginthread and _endthread for thread management rather than CreateThread and ExitThread. Failure to do so results in small memory leaks when the thread calls ExitThread."***
DO NOT USE ExitThread without being aware of the consequences!

Answer (score 2):

Is your process supposed to finish when your thread is done? There could be a lot of explanations for the problem you described. If you want to terminate the entire process, just call `ExitProcess`.

The problem with `TerminateThread` is that is very likely to cause a memory leak. It doesn't care about the thread state, nor its allocated resources. It may also cause a deadlock, depending on how you're doing synchronisation. In other words, it does not terminate it gracefully.

The best way to terminate a thread is to not terminate it explicitly. Do not call `TerminateThread` nor `ExitThread`, but just `return` from the thread's function. You may need to use an atomic flag, or fire an event (or another synchronisation method) to signal when the thread should terminate. Then your thread should periodically check that flag (or event) and deallocate all resources before returning (terminating).

Comment: Thanks for your reply jweyrich, my problem is solved, i follow the instruction from Selbie, and as you said, it's just return from thread's function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SingleWaitObjects or QueueUserAPC but you have to make sure that the thread stops to check these async objects or wait for one in it's end and terminate the thread normally .. in linux you can use signals

Comment: Thanks for your reply CMAF-CMAC. My problem is now gone. i just follow instruction from Selbie.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you need to view each thread like a mini-process (that's what they are under the hood anyway). To get it to shutdown cleanly you need extra infrastructure in place that let's you- the main thread- tell it to stop.

The simplest way to do this right is a signalling system, which the inventors of POSIX figured out early on and thus expose directly in the OS. The best real-world example of such a system is the US Post Office. Every agent has a unique address from which they can both send and receive mail (signals) from other addresses, and it is up to the agent to decide what do when they get a signal. Some are info or junk, and thus ignored, whereas others are high priority and you ignore them at your peril.

At a code level you need the following to make that work well (I've built a few of these for image processing programs):
1) Some abstract "Event" or "ControlSignal" object. Feel free to use the default Windows events or linux signals if they're adequate.
2) A "Pipe" of some kind: The OS will often have a literal Kernel primitive CALLED a pipe that lets 1 end pull data off while another puts data in. This guy is usually overkill for comms within a process, but the object you need is conceptually equivalent.
 
3) Code within your threads that retrieves signals from the pipe and acts on them.
4) A "stop" or "cancel" signal all threads recognize.

Of course, you CAN just hard abort a thread with TerminateThread just as you can use taskkill or CTRL-C to kill a process. ExitThread is a Windows-specific way to build a clean shutdown signal like I describe in (4), but you still need the while-loop & "WaitForSingleObject" (3) plus the Windows-specific handle (2) to make it work.